# gcc: command not found but already installed

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu-14.04

> k@k-Inspiron-5537:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc

```
[sudo] password for k: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 291 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up matlab-support (0.0.19) ...
No default Matlab path found. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package matlab-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 matlab-support
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

> k@k-Inspiron-5537:~$ gcc -v

```
The program 'gcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Any idea ??

Comment: What did you do at the prompt: `Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.` Did you press `Enter` or `n`? The `Abort.` part suggests you did not continue the install. Try installing again and press `Enter` key or press `y` key.

Comment: @downshift i edit details. please check that

Comment: try `apt-get install matlab-support`

Comment: @downshift you can ignore the matlab part. Its optional

Comment: ok, compare suggestions in this post: [How do I use the latest GCC on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @downshift thanks bro,it worked

Comment: great buddy, glad to hear it help mate

Answer (score 0):

Matlab-support requires matlab to be installed. Do you have mathlab installed? install: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB

Comment: u can ignore the matlab part its optional

Comment: @srk then why does it throw an error after saying it cannot find matlab

Comment: it always do that when i install any new package

Comment: Well, here it clearly says it fails because of it. Try installing it, if that doesnt work then uninstall.